# Call hook from another hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm quite new to react and trying to ease some development.

I'm having this custom hook `useApi`.

```
import {useState} from "react";
import {PetsApiFactory} from "petstore-axios-api"
import {useKeycloak} from "@react-keycloak/web";

const petsApi = new PetsApiFactory({}, `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}`);
export const useApi = () => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const {keycloak} = useKeycloak();

    const createPets = (requestData) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        return petsApi.createPets(requestData, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`
            }
        }).finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    };

    const listPets = (limit = undefined) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        return petsApi.listPets(limit, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`
            }
        }).finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    };

    const showPetById = (petId) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        return petsApi.showPetById(petId, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`
            }
        }).finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    };

    return {
        createPets,
        listPets,
        showPetById,
        isLoading
    }
};
```

I'd like to call it from within another component like in this snippet.

```
useEffect(() => {
    listPets()
        .then(result => setPetsData(result.data))
        .catch(console.log)
}, []);
```

However react is telling me that I'm missing the dependency on `listPets`
`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'listPets'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

I've tried to include `listPets` as a dependency but that leads to repeatable call to backend service. What would be the best way to rewrite the call to `useApi` hook?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change component's useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
   listPets()
    .then(result => setPetsData(result.data))
    .catch(console.log)
}, [listPets]);
```

And then try to wrap listPets function with useCallBack hook like this:

```
const showPetById = useCallback((petId) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    return petsApi.showPetById(petId, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`
        }
    }).finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
},[petsApi]);
```

Comment: I've just changed the dependency of `useCallback` from `[petsApi]` to `[keycloak.token]` and it's seems to be working. Can you explain this a bit? I will accept your answer as correct then. Thank you

Comment: useCallback helps us to memoize the function, so when the component re-renders function which is wrapped using useCallback won't be generated again, so useEffect won't be triggered. here is the link (more details about useCallback)  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback.

Answer (score 1):

you have forget to add listPets into useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
listPets()
    .then(result => setPetsData(result.data))
    .catch(console.log)
}, [listPets]);
```

Comment: that leads to repeatable call to api... so I can overload the server with it.